# The `%in%` operation is not correct for integer64

Tags: r, bit64, integer64

The `%in%` operator is not providing correct output for integer64

```
x <- bit64::as.integer64("9219348897572232380")
y <- bit64::as.integer64("9221407835133917342")
x == y
# FALSE
x %in% y
# TRUE
```

Comment: I guess you need `"%in%.integer64"(x, y)#
[1] FALSE`

Comment: Thanks. I did not call `library(bit64)` before. It was not calling `%in%.integer64` function. After calling `bit64` library, `%in%` also outputs correct answer. Thanks

Comment: The `%in%` was not dispatched as you didn't load the library

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that I didn't call the `library(bit64)`, hence, bit64 specific `%in%` wasn't dispatched. Thanks @akrun

```
library(bit64)
x <- bit64::as.integer64("9219348897572232380")
y <- bit64::as.integer64("9221407835133917342")
x == y
# FALSE
x %in% y
# FALSE
```